# glue job script is failing when trying to write dynamic df to redshidft

Tags: python, excel, pyspark, amazon-redshift

redshift_table = redshift_schema +."'+redshift_table+ print('redshift_table is:',redshift_table) pre_query = "truncate table " + redshift_table # print("CSV Dataframe is ", dynamic_df.printSchema()) #dynamic_df.show(100)

try:

dynamic_write = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(

frame = dynamic_df,

catalog_connection redshift_conn, #"preactions":pre_query, connection_options ("preactions":pre_query, "dbtable": redshift_table, "database": redshift_db), redshift_tmp_dir = redshift_temp_dir I )

print('Redshift table Done') except Exception as e: print("failing due to error", e)

I'm using this script to write bunch of Excel file data to redshidft, all Excel workbook have multiple sheets.
The script is able to write the data to redshidft for most of the files but for one it's is giving below error

An error occurred while calling 0770.pywriteDynamicFrame.

: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task @ in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 6) (10.182.253.49 executor 3): ExecutoriostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network Issues

I'm trying to understand what could be the reason it is failing for only one file